# Mongo Db array filter ($filter)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have simple mongo collection:

```
{
  ...
  customerProducts: [
    { organizationId: ObjectId('x') },
    { organizationId: ObjectId('y') },
    { organizationId: ObjectId('z') },
  ]
  ...
}
```

I need to filter array `customerProducts` and to keep the elements with `organizationId = ObjectId('x')`.
I try to do it via `$filter`. My approach:

```
aggregation([{
  $project: {
    'customerProducts': {
      $fiter: {
        input: '$customerProducts',
        as: 'item',
        cond: { $eq: ['$$item.organizationId', ObjectId('x') }
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

But Compass argues - "Stage must be a properly formatted document". What did I do wrong?

Comment: 1) the operator name should be `$filter` not `$fiter` 2) missing closing `]` array bracket of `$eq` => `cond: { $eq: ['$$item.organizationId', ObjectId('x')] }`

Comment: thanks, but still doesn't work.

Comment: use an editor to help you with auto pairing the [] and {} its hard to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't wrap `$filter` content with `{}`. Change your code like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "customerProducts": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$customerProducts",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$this.organizationId",
              ObjectId("111111111111111111111111")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/euHfM_YECKe)